# Is this a sound proof of the fact that $a_n <C$ infinitely often?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, inequality, proof-writing

Let $a_n, b_n, c_n$ be real positive sequences. Assume $a_n\to C>0$, and that $a_n$ is not monotone on any neighborhood of $+\infty$. Suppose also the following lemmata have been proven:

**Lemma 1.** *Whenever $a_n\ge a_{n-1}$ one has $b_n\ge c_n$.*

**Lemma 2.** *For infinitely many $n$ one has $\dfrac{a_nb_n}{c_n}< C$.*

Now say we want to establish that $a_n<C$ infinitely often. Then a possible approach is showing that if $a_{n-1}-C>0$ for some $n$, then $a_n<a_{n-1}$: this implies $a_n-C$ must attain infinitely many negative values because otherwise $a_n$ would be eventually decreasing, which contradicts our hypothesis.

I would like to know if the following reasoning is sound:

given an arbitrary $n$, assume without loss of generality that $a_{n-1}>C$, and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $a_n\ge a_{n-1}$. So in particular we're assuming $a_n\ge a_{n-1}>C$. But combining Lemma 1 and Lemma 2 we get that, for some choice of $n$, we have $a_n<C\dfrac{c_n}{b_n}<C.$ This is absurd, because we could have picked such an $n$ in our initial assumptions, in which case we should have $a_n> C$. It follows that $a_{n-1}>C$ implies $a_n<a_{n-1}$.

Comment: What would mean that "$a_n$ is not monotone on any neighborhood of $+\infty$" ?

Comment: @JamesGroon It means that it is neither eventually (non-)decreasing nor eventually (non-)increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect as you can get unlucky and the inequality in Lemma 2 holds only for $a_{n-1}$ which is lower than $a_{n} ,a_{n-2}$ so no restrictions on $b_{n-1},c_{n-1}$

$a_{2n}=C+\frac{1}{n+1}, a_{2n-1}= C+\frac{1}{2^n+100}, b_{2n}=c_{2n}=1, 100b_{2n-1}=c_{2n-1}=1$ satisfy your conditions but $a_{n}>C$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I forgot to say that $b_n $ and $c_n $ are strictly increasing to $+\infty $, does that change anything?

Comment: No - make $b_{2n}=c_{2n}=200^{2n}, c_{2n+1}=200^{2n+1}, b_{2n+1}=2(200)^{2n}$ - ratios are as before and now both sequences increase to infinity